# httpClient proxy support in apache commons 3.1

Tags: java, apache, proxy, apache-commons

I am using apache commons 3.1 to implement httpClient with proxy support.
I am trying to connect to a remote host through proxy. The proxy server is configured without any authentication, however the the remote host is configured with authentication. 
When I am passing the proxy parameters through properties file, it gives warning while execution:

WARN - Required proxy credentials not available for BASIC @xx.xx.xx.xx
WARN - Preemptive authentication requested but no default proxy credentials availble

But the execution goes ahead.

On the other hand when I am passing the proxy parameters through the JVM arguments then the again the same warning is given and the execution is stopped.

Is there any specific reason for this behavior? Is there any difference in passing the proxy parameters through properties file and through JVM arg?

Here is the code:

```
if(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost") != null && System.getProperty("http.proxyPort") != null) {
            httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"), Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort")));
        }
        else if(AMXAdminTask.props.getProperty("http.proxyHost") != null && AMXAdminTask.props.getProperty("http.proxyPort") != null) {
            httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(Propfile.props.getProperty("http.proxyHost"), Integer.parseInt(Propfile.props.getProperty("http.proxyPort")));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to combine two very different things. The code you posted above properly gets you through your proxy, but the remote host requires BASIC authentication. The below example uses the Jersey client (used in an existing project for making RESTful calls), but you should get the idea of what you need to do. If you're stuck on using Apache HttpComponents, take a look at this: 
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.ApacheHttpClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig;

public abstract class BaseProxyProvider {
    protected Client getHttpClient() {
        final DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig cc = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"))) {
            cc.getProperties()
                    .put(ApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_PROXY_URI,
                            "http://" + System.getProperty("http.proxyHost") + ":"
                                    + System.getProperty("http.proxyPort") + "/");
        }
        Client c = ApacheHttpClient.create(cc);

        c.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(WebAppPropertyReader.getProperties().getProperty(
                WebAppPropertyReader.SERVICE_USER), WebAppPropertyReader.getProperties().getProperty(
                WebAppPropertyReader.SERVICE_PASSWORD)));
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to test the proxy server with fiddler with the same code. I could pass the proxy parameters both from properties file and JVM ags.

Comment: Right now I am having an issue regarding the authentication at proxy server. I am using fiddler as proxy server. I have authentication both at proxy server and at remote host. I am setting the http proxy credentials in the httpClient header. But I am getting an error in the response: "Transport error 407: Proxy Authentication Required." and in the fiddler I am seeing a message: "No WWW-Authenticate Header is present."

Comment: You need to set System properties for your Proxy user and password:
    `System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);`
    `System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);`

Comment: @DomenicD. That may not be desired in all cases.  HttpClient allows you to specify the credentials for the proxy in code.